# The sum of all the elements of every non empty subset of $A$ is not a multiple of $n$

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, additive-combinatorics

Let $N=\{1,2,\ldots ,n\},n>1$. We wish to construct a set $A\subseteq N$ with the property:

> The sum of all the elements of every non empty subset of $A$ is **not** a
>   multiple of $n$.

Question: What is the maximum value of $|A|$?

It is obvious that if $\quad$ $T_m=1+2+\ldots +m=\frac{m(m+1)}{2}$ and $T_m<n$, then $|A|\geq m$.
This gives immediately $\max|A|\geq c\cdot \sqrt{n}$.
Is it possible to obtain something more accurate?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/44309 indicates that this value is called the restricted Davenport number of the cyclic group $C_n$, and that it is (asymptotically?) bounded above by $\sqrt{2n}$, which matches your lower bound.

Comment: As @EmilJeřábek notes, $\sqrt{2n}$ is the precise asymptotic value of $\max{|A|}$. Your construction gives the lower bound, while the result of Y. O. Hamidoune and G. Zemor in the paper *On zero-free subset sums* (Acta Arithmetica, 1996) supplies an upper bound of $\sqrt{2n} + O(n^{1/3}\log{n})$ (with a much better error term if $n$ is prime). For $n$ prime, a bound of the form $\max{|A|} < C \sqrt{n}$ already goes back to the 1964 Acta Arithmetica paper *On the addition of residue classes mod $p$* by Erdos and Heilbronn.